# Move HTML Background when Arrow Keys are Pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, background

Given a html page with a background image on the body, how could you move the background when arrow keys are pressed on the keyboard e.g. the background scrolls right when the left key is pressed, scrolls left when the right key is pressed etc.

Answer (score 4):

The background image position can be controlled using the background-position css property, which you can set from your javascript code.

In the below example, jquery is used to fire an event when a key is pressed and depending on which arrow key is pressed, the background-position-x or background-position-y properties are adjusted in increments of 10 pixels.

```js
var initX = 0;
var initY = 0;
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 38) {//up
      initY += 10;
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundPositionY = initY + "px";
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 40) {//down
      initY -= 10;
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundPositionY = initY + "px";
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 37) {//left
      initX += 10;
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundPositionX = initX + "px";
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 39) {//right
      initX -= 10;
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundPositionX = initX + "px";
    }
});
```

```css
body{
    background-image: url("https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/apollo_17_-_resize.jpg"); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    some content
</body>
```